# C# Between Strings

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a strings between strings by using this code reference `https://www.dotnetperls.com/between-before-after`

But I am having some type of problem my string are contain with uncountable `","` (Which means in each line are not the same amount).

For Example

```
string a = "hello,test,test2,finish";
```

code

```
label1.Text = a.Between("," , ",");
```

And I want to get only `test` ,where it is in position 1.
But my output is `test,test2`

So I want to know that how can I get only `test`. Also `hello` and `test2` are always changing (meaning is the data is not "test2" and "hello").

Thank you.

Comment: `"(?:,)(test)(?:,)"`

Comment: Well, `String.Split` is a thing.

Comment: @Freggar Also the data is not (test) too. and it not the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> test position in indexing  is 1 NOT 2

This will give you `test`

```
string wanted = a.Split(',')[1];
```

since it's index is 1 always

Comment: Wowww. Its work Thank you very much. I can't accept this answer. IDK Why...

Comment: *Programming* in general don't always use **0-based indexes**, so your first sentence isn't technically correct.

Comment: @Rafalon VB flashbacks *shudder*

Comment: @Eddga You can only accept after a certain amount of time after asking. This is to encourage more answers to be posted which might be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it,

```
var a = "hello,test,test2,finish";
var result = tx.Split(',').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

result = test, for your data
result = null - when you have less data required. a = "hello";